# 'webkit-text-size-adjust' not working when sent from Outlook 2010 - HTML email signature

Tags: iphone, html, ios, email, signature

I'm ready to explode with frustration with a HTML email signature I am building, it's fine when attaching the signature using Thunderbird, but sending from outlook 2010 (which my client uses to send email from) chucks up a load of issues - here's the two main ones:

1. The '-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%' / '-webkit-text-size-adjust:none' doesn't seem to work, which means the font formatting on iphone / ipad is oversized and looks real ugly.
2. When sending from Outlook 2010 and reading in Hotmail (which is now actually 'Outlook', which makes this issue even more annoying) - it whacks a load of gaps between lines of text. I'm aware of the 'display:block' to get rid of gaps, but that only applies to images I suppose?

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks

Comment: same issue, looks like mail client filters `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none`, maybe no workaround for it.

Comment: Can you post your code? You can embedded in your post (my preference), or set up a jsfiddle or codepen.